# Ionic & Visual Studio/Cordova - Ionic not working

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-cordova

I am just getting started developing an app with Ionic in the new Visual Studio Apache Cordova Tools.

I have created a home page using one of the Ionic tutorials (almost copy and paste) and tested it in the Ripple Emulator as well as on a real device, both run with the same result.
They both run fine as apps but Ionic fails to render anything.

In Visual Studio I get the following JavaScript error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'content' of undefined"
>
> File: ionic.js, Line 3898, Column: 23

This is where the ionic.js file tries to set the property of `viewportTag.content` but the `viewport` variable is undefined.

```
function viewportTagUpdate() {
   var key, props = [];
   for (key in viewportProperties) {
     if (viewportProperties[key]) {
       props.push(key + (viewportProperties[key] == '_' ? '' : '=' + viewportProperties[key]));
     }
   }

   viewportTag.content = props.join(', ');
}
```

The `viewportTag.content = props.join(', ');` is where the error is.

This is my HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />

    <title>Test Tabs App</title>

    <link href="/Content/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="/cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/viewScripts/Home.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/packages/ionic/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <ion-tabs>
        <ion-tab class="tabs-positive" title="Home">
            <ion-content>
                <p>Home Tab</p>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-tab>
        <ion-tab title="About">
            <ion-content>
                <p>About Tab</p>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>
</body>
</html>
```

Has anyone ran into this problem with Ionic before and knows how to solve it?

-Kyle

Comment: +1 I've got the same problem with that particular line whenever I change the orientation on ripple, hoping it's related if someone happens to come along and share some insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to update the shim. This sample may help:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Ionic-SideMenu-Starter-8e905eb5

For more info:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdn_answers/archive/2015/02/10/running-cordova-apps-on-windows-and-windows-phone-8-1-using-ionic-angularjs-and-other-frameworks.aspx